# My Arduino project only works when the car is off. Why is this the case?

Tags: arduino, i2c, emi-filtering

I have been all over the internet and have asked a few people why this is happening. Hopefully I'm at the right place.

My Arduino project consists of reading serial data from my car, which is OBDI-compliant. I have provided some links for easier reading and understanding below. The output stream is fed to the board and prints the data to an OLED screen. When my car engine is OFF but the key is ON, the board reads the data and prints it to the screen without error. I have also verified that it is printing serial data to the terminal in the IDE. However, when I turn the engine ON, the board reads the data but refuses to print it to the screen. The OLED is using I2C protocol.

I suspect that EMI/RFI from the spark plugs, alternator, etc. are to blame, but so far attempts to mitigate this have proven futile. I have twisted wires and have even put the project in a metal box to no avail. My circuit is not finalized - I have it built on a breadboard and I think it works fine.

Am I right to assume that EMI is the cause? I also tried using a 4N25 optocoupler to isolate the signal ground from the Arduino ground, but this proved to be just as useless. Does anyone have any suggestions?

https://forum.arduino.cc/t/reading-obd-1-data-from-toyota-corrola-1992/231151
https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/13dt07r/toyota_obdi_reader_wip_please_help/
https://www.reddit.com/r/CarHacking/comments/13eq64v/1993_camry_obdi_data_reader_issues/

Rough schematic here:
[image]

Full schematic with optocoupler based off of Fritzing breadboard design:
[Removed]

5-18 Update: In searching around, I found a more refined schematic:
[image]

Comment: How is your circuit powered?  Twisting wires and enclosure shielding don't count for much when you are feeding the entire thing with gross power, which "battery only vs. alternator" sounds like.

Comment: Please add schematics and PCB layout here.

Comment: My circuit is powered by 5VDC via the USB port on the board. I am not using the VIN pin. My car's DLC port can provide 12V but I haven't tried this as I'm afraid I'd blow the board up.

Comment: Where is the 5V coming from?  If you are powering the board through the +5V pin, then you are not getting the PSRR and slight filtering from the input caps that the VIN pin will give you.

Comment: 5V is coming from the USB port via the car's accessory plug charger. It powers the board via the USB plug. I am powering the OLED via the 5V pin.

Comment: Lack of decoupling capacitors? Poor layout? Brownout during engine start and fails to initialize?

Comment: I know it's still a WIP which is why it's so barebones. Would building the optocoupler circuit like this help?: <https://europe1.discourse-cdn.com/arduino/optimized/4X/d/8/6/d86072f78fad20a0b7b1f7108a749a73664728ec_2_1035x703.png>

Comment: Those Fritzing diagrams make it so much harder to clearly see what the circuit is trying to do. Do you have a real schematic of this opto-coupler circuit..?

Comment: Post an annotated schematic showing exactly how it is wired included all connections. Be sure to show power sources etc. You are proving a point that the automotive electrical environment is not a simple 12V system. All of the components interact with each other in unexpected ways.

Comment: *Please post a photograph of the circuit*. You're likely suffering from the effects of ground loops. Use a local regulator to generate 5V from the 12V available in the OBDI circuit, and have the only connections from the board go to the OBDI connector, and to the display. Do not use external USB supplies etc. - they can be quite problematic here.

Comment: What happens if you power it off a usb power bank or even 3x AA batteries? I suspect the usb power source being dirty/cheap.

Comment: Which OLED module that is? Is there any link or specs or datasheet or manual? What voltages it supports (both as supply and IO bus)? Do any of the boards have pull-up resistors for I2C bus?

Comment: Okay I tried with a USB power pack an no go. It still did the same thing. As for the OLED display, I'm using a generic SSD1306. I don't think the boards have pullup resistors but I could be wrong. I will get a schematic of the diagnostic reader with the optocoupler circuit soon.

Comment: I can't decipher what the picture with the optocoupler should even do. It has LEDs upside down and likely transistor too. I hope you did not burn your ODB port with that. And "generic SSD1306" means nothing. It's just a driver chip that needs 3.3V IO supply and 7V to 15V for LEDs. You have a specific OLED module with SSD1306 and some other electronics to work, and you need to know how to connect it. Which module it is, what kind of manual, data sheet or instructions it has how to use it?

Comment: I'm not sure what model it is, I bought them from Amazon. I will look today at the brand. I ditched the opto circuit and used the standalone board and OLED because I didn't trust the fact that the LEDs were backwards and there were some things I didn't understand about the circuit. I tried using a standalone 4N25 but this didn't work either. I will see what I can find about those OLEDs but I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: I highly doubt that I burned out my ECU and OBDI port because it can still send serial data.

Comment: Consider powering the arduino via a laptop usb or phone charger cube, and then only connect serial lines and guns to te obd port. This will tell you if you’re having dirty power issues or not.

Comment: I found some photos on the gentleman's Facebook page who originally built this. This is the best photo of his PCB I could find: <https://scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.18172-8/1956889_10152361711131174_808247429403040654_o.jpg?_nc_cat=106&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=cdbe9c&_nc_ohc=7KlRf2CiiqcAX9v_kqj&_nc_ht=scontent-yyz1-1.xx&oh=00_AfA7hYOfwQWC-SvGJf6Tu7GB63sq4v3XSjVbmZl3WFzzrg&oe=648EE3D0>. It looks like he used a voltage regulator which means it's drawing power from the 12V supply on the OBDI pin. I might try this and see what happens.